# Using nginx to serve both node.js and php generated content

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx, node.js

I maintain a Ubuntu host that runs a website powered by a node.js
They've recently requested to add a WP blog to be served as well. I've install php3-fpm and Wordpress and modified my nginx.conf as suggested on the nginx site.
My nginx root comes from the default config and points to /usr/shares/nginx/html
I placed a simple php script there to test this whole set up.
The php generated output is not seen. Instead I see my php script being downloaded as a plain ascii file.
This is how my nginx.conf now looks like:

`server {
    listen      80;
    server_name myhost.com www.myhost.com;
    return      301 https://www.myhost.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen  443 ssl;
    server_name www.myhost.com;`

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.com/fullchain.pem ;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.com/privkey.pem ;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location /ad_image {
    root /home/me/www ;
}

location /robots.txt {
    alias /home/me/robots.txt ;
    access_log off ;
}

location /sitemap.xml {
    alias /home/me/sitemap.xml ;
    access_log off ;
}
```

}

Comment: You are missing a `root` directive. It's not clear from your question where WordPress is installed and what URI you wish to access it with.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks for pointing out to the incompleteness of my questions. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume you have installed PHP correctly. If not, install it using "sudo apt-get install php5-fpm"
2. Make sure you have changed cgi.fix_pathinfo to zero in php.ini
3. Make sure you have set correct path in FPM config file "/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf"

change "listen = 127.0.0.1:9000" to "listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock"

4. Restart the php-fpm and nginx to take affect.

sudo service php5-fpm restart;
sudo service nginx restart

Comment: Could you perhaps give a little more explanation and possibly some sample syntax that may improve this answer?